# Setting up a proxy for native apps to record HTTPS traffic for performance testing

Tags: android, proxy, jmeter, performance-testing, nativeapplication

I am using JMeter to record our native apps for performance testing purpose. I have installed my JMeter certificate to my android device and using android version 5.1.

I have a rooted android device and using proxy droid for forcing all apps to use proxy. Seems like Youtube and playstore is working and I am able to record everything. I am just not able to record anything from my android app. It looks like the internet is somehow not working in my particular app. My app is sending HTTPS Request.

Same Problem with IOS.

I have also used Blazemeter but same problem with it.

1) What should I do to make it work?

2) What should I tell to developer to make that app work with proxy setting?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can only record HTTP and HTTPS traffic with its [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), the fact you can capture the traffic from Youtube and Play store indicates the fact that your JMeter configuration is correct, most probably your application uses a different protocol for communication and you should talk to the developer and learn which protocol(s) are in scope and investigate if there is a load testing tool available in the market which supports record and replaying of this protocol traffic.

As a last resort you can capture "raw" traffic using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and replay it with [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) JMeter plugin but this way you won't be able to perform [correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), [assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When I set up the Proxy in my mobile device and after installing the certificate, I was not able to connect to the Internet. I tried multiple options but it wasn't allowing me to record traffic. After some research I got the solution and it is simple.

For iOS follow below steps after setting up the Proxy on your mobile device to get Internet connection and record Traffic:

- Step 1: Click on Settings
- Step 2: Select General
- Step 3: Select About
- Step 4: Certificate Trust Settings
- Step 5: Enable CA Certificate you downloaded from JMeter

That's it. Try to access Internet on your mobile after clicking on the *Start* option on Jmeter HTTPS Test Script Recorder. You will see your traffic is getting recorded.

If you are still facing problems, please reach out to me.